# Quillen equivalence between sSet (Joyal's model structure) and sSetCat (Bergner's one)

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Let me consider two model categories:

- $ \mathsf{sSet} $:
  the category of simplicial sets with Joyal model structure,
- $ \mathsf{sSetCat} $:
  the category of simplicially enriched categories with Bergner model structure.

In Lurie's "Higher Topos Theory", he showed there is a Quillen equivalence between them.
Lurie denote it as:

- $ \operatorname{N}: \mathsf{sSetCat} \to \mathsf{sSet} $:
  homotopy coherent nerve,
- $ \mathfrak{C}: \mathsf{sSet} \to \mathsf{sSetCat} $.

However, his proof
is not easy to follow I think, because of so many hyperlinks.

Is there another proof on this fact,
or a document which explains the outline of his proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a second proof that followed Lurie's rather quickly. https://arxiv.org/abs/0911.0469